# On the "solvability" of jigsaw Sudoku puzzles

Tags: constraint-programming, sudoku

I am making a computer program that is going to generate Sudoku puzzles of various types. One of these types is "jigsaw", in which the board is split into rows, columns and random 9-square contiguous regions. My regions are generated completely randomly and I have become concerned that maybe there are some arrangements of region for which no solution can exist. Can anybody give me an example of this or perhaps explain why no such arrangement exists. Thank you.

Comment: When you say 'no solution can exist', do you mean 'it can be shrunk down to a sudoku puzzle that can't be solved', or do you mean 'there is no Latin Square assignment that makes certain that each jigsaw region contains the numbers 1-9'?

Comment: that there is no latin square assignment.

Comment: @maxG795 Are your contiguous regions completely disjoint, and  not necessarily 3 x 3 boxes?  And are there exactly 9 regions, so that the regions cover the entire board?

Comment: I found a non $9\times 9$ example.